# HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR missing from servervariables in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ip

I would like to get the ClientIPaddress but when I call to `Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]` I always get `NULL`.

After checking the list of the `Servervariables` I noticed that `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` is not in the list of options.

Anyone knows how this is possible and how to solve? Or is it normal that this option is not in the list and I'm missing something.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What about `REMOTE_ADDR` ?

Comment: This is returning ::1 --> ip6v equivalent of 127.0.0.1 - As I have searched the net to get the client address you first check the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR. If this is null then u get the remote_addr because this is returning a less accurate ip address, router or ... thx for answering btw

Comment: perhaps this is what you mean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413171/i-want-to-try-to-check-the-ip-using-servervariablesremote-addr-but-it-keeps

Answer (score 11):

`Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]` will only have a value, if the request was forwarded by a proxy. Usually you will get the client IP by using `Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]`.

Comment: Indeed, but that doesn't explain when i debug request.servervariables and check all the keys that this list doesn't contain a listitem for HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR

Comment: Well, if there is no proxy involved, the header will never be present. If you're debugging you're most likely requesting on localhost and therefor not making a request through any kind of proxy. If you can you might use Cloudflare for one of your domains or subdomains. They will even add some more headers to the incoming request…

Answer (score 6):

```
public string GetIPAddress()
{
    System.Web.HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
    string ipAddress = context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress))
    {
        string[] addresses = ipAddress.Split(',');
        if (addresses.Length != 0)
        {
            return addresses[0];
        }
    }

    return context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}
```

This method maybe useful for you.

Comment: I try this code but what I get is "::1". I don't get the IP address.

Comment: I try this code but what I get is "::1". I saw somewhere that it is IPv6 IP address. how can I get its equivalent IPv4 address (like "xxx.xxx.x.xx" this format)?

Comment: The second `if` is not needed. If the `ipAddress` is not empty and it does not contain any `,` then the `address` will contain a single element with will be equivalent to `ipAddress`.

Answer (score 4):

Please try this:

```
public static string GetUserIP() {   
    var ip = ( HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] != null
          && HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] != "" )
         ? HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]
         : HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    if (ip.Contains( "," ))
        ip = ip.Split( ',' ).First();
    return ip.Trim();
}
```

Found here:
http://mycodepad.wordpress.com/2013/04/26/c-getting-a-user-ip-behind-a-proxy-http_x_forwarded_for/

Comment: Thank you for update that HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR can contain multiple addresses, but I would not recommend to cut it and use the 1st one only. That should be up to developer to decide how to use it

Comment: And I believe that assignment to ip after Trim() is missing.

Answer (score 2):

If you run it on local machine , it's normal to don't see any thing, otherwise you run it in on a real external host.

[.net HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR NULL on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30049942/net-http-x-forwarded-for-null-on-localhost)