# .net HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR NULL on localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-headers, ip

Apologises if this has been answered else where, I could not find it.

In the case it has not, I am trying to find the original IP of a machine who has accessed the site.

In my basic understanding, the variable `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` will display the user's IP regardless of proxy's and other filters. if this is true, I am trying to code this but I get a null string

```
System.Web.HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
string ipAddress = context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
```

Possible problems are `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` doesn't appear in the HTTP HEADERS / server variable list, or I am using localhost? Using `REMOTE_ADDR`, the localhost IP is displayed.

Am I on the right lines or is my understanding incorrect?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR header usually hold proxy values so it is normal you dont see any content on your local machine since you are not going through any proxies

Comment: Great. I understand. So when I realise it to an external DNS, the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR  value will not be NULL?

Comment: Yes should be the case however some firewall change the request headers so you need to make a test to make sure

Comment: SO = Stackoverflow, It prevents you from marking an answer for some time.