# C# get client ip address Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]

Tags: c#

I want to get the client IP address in tool class, but I got an error when calling `Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]`. The error message is:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Here is the code :

```
    public static string GetIpAddress()
    {
        string _stringIpAddress = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            _stringIpAddress = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
            if (_stringIpAddress == null)
            {
                _stringIpAddress = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
            }
        }           
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logging.LogError(string.Concat("GetIpAddress()", ex.Message));
        }
        return _stringIpAddress;
    }
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you checked whether it is Request that is null or ServerVariables?

Comment: What line threw the exception ?

Comment: how to check? as this method is in tool class, Do I need initialize Request and how? I am fresh on C#.

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa this line: _stringIpAddress = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

Comment: I found this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17521277/http-x-forwarded-for-missing-from-servervariables-in-c-sharp?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa, tried 'HTTP_CONNECTION', but same error show up. So, it means no Request caught?

Comment: Hum...Interesting, When do you call your function ?

Comment: Try this 
`var current =  System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
                var request = current.Request;
                var ServerVariables = request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
                _stringIpAddress = ServerVariables;` add breakpoint and the beginning and see which one of them throws the exception.